# Cannot modify the return value of 'Transform.rotation' because it is not a variable

Tags: c#

I am new to unity and I need help with this code. I need some help with this.

```
    if (Input.GetKey("d"))
    {
        yr = PlayerModel.transform.rotation.y - 1f * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        PlayerModel.transform.rotation.y = yr;
    }
```

yr is just a float. PlayerModel is my game object. And this is under my Update void.
I'm trying to create almost like a tank turning system. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnRrD.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `Transform.Rotate()`?

```
PlayerModel.transform.Rotate(Vector3 eulers, Space relativeTo = Space.Self);

PlayerModel.transform.Rotate(float xAngle, float yAngle, float zAngle, Space relativeTo = Space.Self);

PlayerModel.transform.Rotate(Vector3 axis, float angle, Space relativeTo = Space.Self);

PlayerModel.transform.Rotate(Vector3 eulers);

PlayerModel.transform.Rotate(Vector3 axis, float angle);
```

More info:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

So in your case, it can be

```
PlayerModel.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * -1f * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Also you can use `Transform.eularAngles = new Vector3(x, y, z);`

```
PlayerModel.transform.eularAngles = new Vector3(
    PlayerModel.transform.eularAngles.x,
    yr,
    PlayerModel.transform.eularAngles.z
);
```

If you are still want to use transform.rotation,

```
PlayerModel.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(
    PlayerModel.transform.eularAngles.x,
    yr,
    PlayerModel.transform.eularAngles.z
);
```

Please keep in mind that to rotate the transform relative to the transform rotation of the parent, you need to use `localRotation` or `localEulerAngles`.

Comment: when using PlayerModel.transform.rotate(Vector3.up * -1f * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime); it returns ''Transform' does not contain a definition for 'rotate' and no accessible extension method 'rotate' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform' could be found'

Comment: sorry, it was a typo. PlayerModel.transform.rotate -> PlayerModel.transform.Rotate

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        Tank.transform.eulerAngles -= new Vector3(Tank.transform.eulerAngles.x, 1f * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Tank.transform.eulerAngles.z);
    else if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        Tank.transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(Tank.transform.eulerAngles.x, 1f * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Tank.transform.eulerAngles.z);
```

My friend who has a lot of experience in Unity helped me with this, works fine now! Thanks for your help.

Comment: PlayerModel.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * -1f * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
I think it's more professional

Answer (score 0):

One way of setting specific angles in unity:

```
    GameObject PlayerCharacter = GameObject.FindWithTag("ThePlayer");
    int RotationY = 0;
    int RotationX = 0;
    int RotationZ = 0;
    PlayerCharacter.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(RotationX, RotationY, RotationZ);
```